# translation from pine to python

Tags: python, translation

Below script is what I copied from tradingview.com. I'm trying to understand the language and I want to translate the script into Python. link page is https://www.tradingview.com/chart/0AZVjf79/ the indicator is called Ehlers Instantaneous Trendline the one created by Alex Orekhov (everget)

There are several sentences that puzzle me. 1. is 'periodMult' in function 'computeComponent(src, periodMult)' a single value or a series? 2. in the function of '_eit(src)', is everything calculated as series? Thus, to translate into Python, they should be several iterations? 3. is there iteration for smoothPeriod? 4. is dcPeriod a single value or a series? 5. how is the interation for 'for i = 0 to dcPeriod - 1' work? the direction is different from python then? Thank you!!!

```
 //@version=3
// Copyright (c) 2018-present, Alex Orekhov (everget)
// Ehlers Instantaneous Trendline script may be freely distributed under the MIT license.
study("Ehlers Instantaneous Trendline", shorttitle="EIT", overlay=true)

src = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
applyFilling = input(title="Apply Ribbon Filling ?", type=bool, defval=true)

// Truncated Hilbert transform
hilbertTransform(src) =>
    0.0962 * src + 0.5769 * nz(src[2]) - 0.5769 * nz(src[4]) - 0.0962 * nz(src[6])

computeComponent(src, periodMult) =>
    hilbertTransform(src) * periodMult

computePart(src) =>
    0.2 * src + 0.8 * nz(src[1])

// FIR Filter
_fir(src) =>
    (4 * src + 3 * nz(src[1]) + 2 * nz(src[2]) + nz(src[3])) / 10

fir = _fir(src)

_eit(src) =>
    PI = 2 * asin(1)

    mesaPeriod = 0.0
    mesaPeriodMult = 0.075 * nz(mesaPeriod[1]) + 0.54

    detrender = 0.0
    detrender := computeComponent(fir, mesaPeriodMult)

    // Compute InPhase and Quadrature components
    I1 = nz(detrender[3])
    Q1 = computeComponent(detrender, mesaPeriodMult)

    // Advance the phase of I1 and Q1 by 90 degrees
    jI = computeComponent(I1, mesaPeriodMult)
    jQ = computeComponent(Q1, mesaPeriodMult)

    I2 = 0.0
    Q2 = 0.0

    // Phasor addition for 3 bar averaging
    I2 := I1 - jQ
    Q2 := Q1 + jI

    // Smooth the I and Q components before applying the discriminator
    I2 := computePart(I2)
    Q2 := computePart(Q2)

    // Homodyne Discriminator
    Re = I2 * nz(I2[1]) + Q2 * nz(Q2[1])
    Im = I2 * nz(Q2[1]) - Q2 * nz(I2[1])

    Re := computePart(Re)
    Im := computePart(Im)

    if Re != 0 and Im != 0
        mesaPeriod := 2 * PI / atan(Im / Re)

    if mesaPeriod > 1.5 * nz(mesaPeriod[1])
        mesaPeriod := 1.5 * nz(mesaPeriod[1])

    if mesaPeriod < 0.67 * nz(mesaPeriod[1])
        mesaPeriod := 0.67 * nz(mesaPeriod[1])

    if mesaPeriod < 6
        mesaPeriod := 6

    if mesaPeriod > 50
        mesaPeriod := 50

    mesaPeriod := 0.2 * mesaPeriod + 0.8 * nz(mesaPeriod[1])

    smoothPeriod = 0.0
    smoothPeriod := 0.33 * mesaPeriod + 0.67 * nz(smoothPeriod[1])

    // Compute Trendline as a SMA over the measured dominant cycle period
    dcPeriod = floor(smoothPeriod + 0.5)

    if dcPeriod < 1
        dcPeriod := 1

    itrend = 0.0

    for i = 0 to dcPeriod - 1
        itrend := itrend + src[i]

    if dcPeriod > 0
        itrend := itrend / dcPeriod

    eit = _fir(itrend)

    if n < 12
        eit := src
    eit

eit = _eit(src)
```

Comment: did you manage to get this implemented?